# How to do implicit differentiation to get an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

$$ye^{y^2} = x + q $$

Hi I was following a similar question as an example to answer this one and although I have got the answer I don't think my working is correct as I sort of made one part up and I don't fully understand it. I was hoping someone could help and check to see if my working is correct.

Line $1$ is the question and the Last Line is the correct answer but I don't get line $4$ and $5$. I just followed an example I was looking at but I don't actually understand it and I'm pretty sure it's not correct either.

Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step you seem to be confused over is computing $\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)$. This is $$\frac{d}{dx}y^2=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac d{dy}(y^2)=y'\times 2y=2yy'$$ Then the rest of the working follows fine.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense thank you so much :)